# Passing 'component' as prop with 'generic' type

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to passing component as prop with generic type.
But it's not simple way.

**This is what I do:**

I created a functional component that getting props through generic types.

```
export interface CustomInputProps<Item> {
  itemKey?: keyof Item;
}

const CustomInput = <Item extends object>({
  key,
  itemKey,
  name,
  defaultValue,
  ...props
}: PropsWithChildren<CustomInputProps<Item>>) => {
  ...
};
```

and I also created a wrapper component that passing component as props with generic type.

```
type Props<T> = {
  checked?: boolean;
  defaultValue?: string;
  Component: T;
} & BaseInputProps & ExtractProps<T>;

type ExtractProps<TComponentOrTProps> = 
  TComponentOrTProps extends React.ComponentType<infer TProps> 
  ? TProps 
  : TComponentOrTProps;

const InputWrapper: <T extends React.FC<any>>(p: Props<T>) => React.ReactElement<Props<T>> = ({
  defaultValue,
  checked,
  Component,
  ...props,
}) => {
  const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = useState(checked);

  return (
    <>
      {isChecked ? 
        <Input 
          defaultValue={defaultValue}
        /> 
        :
        <Component
          defaultValue={defaultValue}
          {...props}
        >
      }
    </>
  );
};

export InputWrapper;
```

I want to passing component through props and setting component type through generic. (typeof component)

However, I don't think it's a good idea to send the component type by wrapping it with 'FC'.

Is there a better way?

```
<>
  <InputWrapper<FC<CustomInputProps<Keys>>
    key='key'
    name={name}
    defaultValue={defaultValues}
    checked={isChecked}
    Component={CustomInput}
    {...props}
  />
</>
```